# Colon after 'Destination'

Tags: colons

in a novel, if I write this at the start of chapter:

Destination: New York.

Destination New York.

Should I use the colon or not?

Comment: Yes. A colon demands an explanation. So, you must use it.

Comment: Judging by usage, you don't actually need the colon. If you look at the [IMDB list of movie titles containing *Destination*](http://www.imdb.com/find?q=destination&s=tt&ref_=fn_al_tt_mr), most of them don't have a colon (although some do).

Comment: @vickyace No; TrevorD is correct on accepted usage.

Comment: Related: [Colons after a single word (e.g. “Example:”)](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/338209/colons-after-a-single-word-e-g-example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Destination: New York.
>   Destination New York.

Both forms are acceptable, depending on what emphasis (if any) you want to apply.

On the one hand: The [IMDB list of movie titles containing Destination](http://www.imdb.com/find?q=destination&s=tt&ref_=fn_al_tt_mr) shows some with a colon, but most without a colon (Courtesy of prior comment from Peter Shor)

On the other hand: [The Punctutation Guide](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/colon.html) shows the following examples:

> Correct: The bookstore specializes in art, architecture, and graphic design.
>   cc: Tom Smith
>   Attention: Accounts Payable

In each of those cases, an introductory 'word', acting as a 'title' for the following item, is separated from the 'item' itself by a colon.